# How to get popUp on label click ? mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Well i am new to this scripting coming to my issue i am having a form tag with a ID like below :

```
<form id="formid">
 //i have my controls say dropdowns i.e make it 2 .

</form>
```

In My view i am having a Label with Id i assigned :

```
<label id="labelid" >filter it</label>
```

Finally in under my script i written like :

```
$('#labelid').click(function()
{
$('#formid').show();

});
```

On my view screen i am getting two drop-down-lists  mentioned in my FORM tag directly  on my initial page load itself where it should not .
**When i click on label only the form tag content should appear in popup window** .

PS: Well i am using this popup functionality to filter my records in DATATABLE under advanced find option .

Regards

Comment: Why is there a `.` in `$.('#formid')`

Comment: nice notice . its a typo got in when i manually typed to post this .Anything i need to do to things work

Comment: Not sure, it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/gLPnt/ If you mean getting it in a popup window, that's completely different, and I see no attempt made.

Comment: oooh yes i tried my code in jsfiddle its working fine . any ideas i.e js file issue ? present i am using 1.4

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded on your website? jQuery is a JavaScript extension. Other libraries that use `$` will also mess up jQuery if present.

Comment: yes i need the controls in a popup window . I made no effort i need some suggestions on this . How to get the controls in a popup window so i can do things like  i need to apply filters inside popup On datatable.

Comment: Please try google. Using JavaScript's `open` and `write` you can achieve just this. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Ok i will try bro i will get back to you will look into it

Comment: yes i done some looking and trying its looks pretty straight forward but there is no such thing to keep controls in pop up . . When i click on means i am getting new browser window . I hope something like normal dialog popup should be preferable rather a browser window popup . any ideas ?

Comment: Dialogue boxes don't contain HTML so that wouldn't work. Look into jQuery UI Dialog boxes, like these examples here: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/